# Passing parameters to new page in asp.net (in Redirecting)

Tags: asp.net, parameter-passing, redirect, request.querystring

I want to fill Listview in Asp.net with Records which should have link to another page . so when user clicks on one record, they will redirect to new page related to that record.I have many parameters want to keep.

In *page Redirecting*, is there any other way to ***passing parameters*** except with "**`QueryString`**"?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **`Cookies`**

**`SET :`**

```
HttpCookie cookieName = new HttpCookie("Name");
cookieName.Value = "SarahN";
```

**`GET :`**

```
string name = Request.Cookies["Name"].Value;
```

**OR** you can use

**`Application Variables`**

**`SET :`**

```
Application["Name"] = "SarahN";
```

**`GET :`**

```
string Name = Application["Name"].ToString();
```

**OR** you can use the `Context` object

Passing value through context object is another widely used method.

**`MyForm1.aspx.cs`**

```
TextBox1.Text = this.Context.Items["Parameter"].ToString();
```

**`MyForm2.aspx.cs`**

```
this.Context.Items["Parameter"] = TextBox1.Text;
Server.Transfer("MyForm2.aspx", true);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx#S6)

> **Context**
>
> The Context object holds data for a single user, for a single
>   request, and it is only persisted for the duration of the request. The
>   Context container can hold large amounts of data, but typically it is
>   used to hold small pieces of data because it is often implemented for
>   every request through a handler in the global.asax. The Context
>   container (accessible from the Page object or using
>   System.Web.HttpContext.Current) is provided to hold values that need
>   to be passed between different HttpModules and HttpHandlers. It can
>   also be used to hold information that is relevant for an entire
>   request. For example, the IBuySpy portal stuffs some configuration
>   information into this container during the Application_BeginRequest
>   event handler in the global.asax. Note that this only applies during
>   the current request; if you need something that will still be around
>   for the next request, consider using ViewState. Setting and getting
>   data from the Context collection uses syntax identical to what you
>   have already seen with other collection objects, like the Application,
>   Session, and Cache. Two simple examples are shown here:

```
// Add item to
Context Context.Items["myKey"] = myValue;

// Read an item from the
 Context Response.Write(Context["myKey"]);
```

You can also refer:

- [ASP.NET State Management Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Forms Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: I set the cookie in the first page , and redirect to second page , Why Cookie is null on the second page? 
but Application[] is working Fine

Comment: @SarahN:- Without the code it is hard to predict why it is happening so? Also did you mean that Application variable is working for you?

Comment: Yes, it works. but as I remember, Application States are known within all asp.net application. Can I have more local one?

Comment: @SarahN:- Any specific reason for not using the `QueryString`?

Comment: too much variables, also because all of them are numbers , nothing changes when I encrypt them, so its not safe

Comment: @SarahN:- Also you can refer this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx#S6 It gives all the options for transfering the value from one page to another. Hope that helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79084/discussion-between-sarahn-and-rahul-tripathi).